# Deployed Qt Qml Application don't show any window

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to deploy my Qt Application according to [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFHPOZoqzcg).

My app runs successfully on my machine, but when I move it to a different computer, it's executing (I see it working in Task Manager), but no window is opened.

It seems like QML failed to load - I had a similar situation on my machine but I moved the content of Qt qml folder to my executable and it started working after that, is there any reason why it wouldn't work on different PC?

Comment: Run it from the command prompt. Are there any errors on the console?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: @JarMan running via Command Prompt doesn't provide any output at all for me.
I added qDebug and cout, but that also is not printed when running that way.

Comment: If you are on Windows, output will probably only be visible in DebugView (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview).